# How to make this effect accessible for screen-reader and without JS

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

Today i found a [good example to make whole div clickable in a cool way](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MiddleBoxLinks/).

Is there a way to make this effect compatible with Screen-reader and keyboard user and even at least accessible if JS disabled (using css hover).

At the least, the link should be shown somewhere if JS is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

That example uses js to insert the anchor link on hover and is completely inaccessible from the keyboard or to anyone who has js turned off. To make it accessible, put the anchor links in the markup, then use javascript to add a class that will move them offscreen (negative `text-indent` or `display: block; position: absolute; margin-left: -9000px;` (do not use `display: none;`). That way all users will be able to navigate via the links. And please use something besides "Read More" for your linked text. Screenreader users often use the screen buffer to scan the list of all links on the page. Not many things more useless than 12 links that all say "Read More" (use perhaps "Read more about `<article topic>`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want some HTML displayed when Javascript is disabled, you might be interested by the `<noscript>` tag.

For more informations : **[HTML `<noscript>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp)**